# WordPress http site keeps switching to https after logging in

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, .htaccess, https

I'm having this weird issue with a clients WP multi-site. It works correctly until you log in to the admin panel. It then converts the featured images on the homepage posts to `https` making them appear as dead links. If you log out of WP, this problem still exists.

To fix, I go into MySQL and update the `siteurl` to be `http://www.lovebryan.com` instead of `https://www.lovebryan.com`. The images appear correctly again.

In my wp-config, I have the following:

`define('WP_HOME','www.lovebryan.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','www.lovebryan.com');
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.lovebryan.com');`

in my .htaccess I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Why does the `siteurl` keep reverting back to `https`?

Comment: What is in file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/<site> that correspond to you site?

Comment: I don't believe I have access to that. I see the `etc` folder but there is only `php.ini`

Comment: Do you have some sort of plugin that's doing a redirection?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `http://` within your `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` definitions.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.lovebryan.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.lovebryan.com');
```

If you still have issues, try also defining the url (with `http://`) in `functions.php` of your theme.

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://www.lovebryan.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://www.lovebryan.com' );
```

More information can be found here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: I figured it had to do with these. I was updating these as well as `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE` and it wouldn't work correctly when I tried to update all 3. Howcome I don't need to edit `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE`?

Comment: Ok this worked only temporarily. The site is back to doing the weird `https` thing again. I've noticed that once I make the fix, it reverts once I login to the admin panel. @mcbacon40